# Difficulty Overriding Magento 2 File

Tags: php, overrides, xml

I am new to coding in Magento 2.  I am trying to override a file using this guide https://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/, and my file compiles without error, but changes don't take place on the frontend.  I have put the file in a Hello World module called MyTest.  My di.xml file located at app/code/[My_Vendor]/MyTest/etc/di.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" 
type="[My_Vendor]\MyTest\Rewrite\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
</config>
```

and my FinalPriceBox.php file which overwrites vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php and is located at app/code/[My_Vendor]/MyTest/Rewrite/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php is

```
<?php

namespace [My_Vendor]\MyTest\Rewrite\Pricing\Render;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{

    public function _renderAmountMinimal()
    {
        $id = $this->getPriceId() ? $this->getPriceId() : ‘product-minimal-price-’ . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId();
    
        $amount = $this->minimalPriceCalculator->getAmount($this->getSaleableItem());
        if ($amount === null) {
            return ‘’;
        }

        return $this->renderAmount(
            $amount,
            [
                ‘display_label’     => __(‘As low as mytest’),
                ‘price_id’          => $id,
                ‘include_container’ => false,
                ‘skip_adjustments’ => true
            ]
        );
    }
    
}

?>
```

I am not sure what is going wrong.  I do not see any new error messages, and I know that changing the original file does cause the changes I want on the frontend.  I also know that the module is enabled and correctly prints Hello World on a test page.  The guide did not have a composer.json file so my module doesn't have one, and I am not sure if that could cause the problem.  I was wondering if anyone had advice on what might be going wrong

Update:

I tried the two answers below, but for some reason it caused a page glitch as in the pictures below where the product names have been covered for anonymity.

Normal Page

[image: Correct Page]

Glitched Page

[image: Glitched Page]

When I check the exception.log file I see 3 errors

"URL key for specified store already exists"

"Unable to retrive deployment version of static file from the file system"

and

"Reflection Exception Class[My_Vendor]\MyTest\Rewrite\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox does not exist at [My_Website_Folder]/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php"

I have tried looking up each of these errors, but so far the solutions haven't worked.  I also tried running php bin/magento dev:di:info "[My_Vendor]\MyTest\Rewrite\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" which shows the class as being configured.

Comment: after implementation, you need to run the upgrade, deploy command. have you done that?

Comment: I did run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

The reference you mentioned, in that they are overriding the **_getProductCollection()** which is available in the **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php**

And in your case the function you are overriding in your custom file using preference is not available in the vendor file which is **_renderAmountMinimal**

The function name is **renderAmountMinimal** not **_renderAmountMinimal**, so try to use without the **underscore(_)** sign

so,

```
<?php

namespace [My_Vendor]\MyTest\Rewrite\Pricing\Render;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    public function renderAmountMinimal()
    {
        $id = $this->getPriceId() ? $this->getPriceId() : 'product-minimal-price-' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId();
        $amount = $this->minimalPriceCalculator->getAmount($this->getSaleableItem());
        if ($amount === null) {
            return '';
        }

        return $this->renderAmount(
            $amount,
            [
                'display_label'     => __('As low as mytest'),
                'price_id'          => $id,
                'include_container' => false,
                'skip_adjustments' => true
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but for some reason I still have a glitch.  I updated the question with the picture of the glitch.

Comment: First of all you are running in default or production mode, if currently developing the site please enable the developer mode for your site, check deploy mode **php bin/magento deploy:mode:show** if is not set to **developer** then please use **php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer** command. with this you can see error which you mentioned as page glitch with my answer.

Comment: I tried developer.  What should I do for debugging after that?

Comment: Instead of the glitch you will see the actual error in your page, or you can check the log files for the errors

Answer (score 0):

```
app/code/[My_Vendor]/MyTest/Rewrite/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php
```

code like this.

```
 <?php

namespace [My_Vendor]\MyTest\Rewrite\Pricing\Render;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{

    public function renderAmountMinimal()
    {
        $id = $this->getPriceId() ? $this->getPriceId() : 'product-minimal-price-' . $this->getSaleableItem()->getId();
    
        $amount = $this->minimalPriceCalculator->getAmount($this->getSaleableItem());
        if ($amount === null) {
            return '';
        }

        return $this->renderAmount(
            $amount,
            [
                ‘display_label’     => __('As low as mytest'),
                ‘price_id’          => $id,
                ‘include_container’ => false,
                ‘skip_adjustments’ => true
            ]
        );
    }
    
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried the code, but as mentioned in the comment for the other answer, for some reason I still have the glitch which is now shown in the updated question.